# string to array as variable

Tags: php, sql

I have profile id stored in my sql database 
this is my php code

```
public function get_profile_id()
    {
        $this->dao->select('profile_id');
        $this->dao->from($this->getTable());
        $result = $this->dao->get();
        if( !$result ) {
            return array() ;
        }
        return $result->result();
    }

$details = Modelbuttons::newInstance()->get_profile_id();
var_dump ($details) ;  ?>
```

I get this response

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'profile_id' => string '57f03c4d66f4a4f6111111111' (length=24)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'profile_id' => string '55534512113e8042222222222' (length=24)
```

i want send this profile id to an APi with this call

```
$newArr = Modesend::newInstance()->getprofile();
foreach($newArr as $a) {
$values[] = explode(' ', $a['profile_id'])[0];
$profile = "" . implode("','", $values). "";
$data = array('profile_ids' => array($profile));
```

this call not work for me can you help me !

this is the success API call

```
$data = array('profile_ids' => array('57f03c4d66f4a4f6111111111','55534512113e8042222222222')));
```

Comment: why you are exploding

Comment: $profileid = $a['profile_id'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store all values in array you can simply define an array before foreach loop

```
$data = [];
$newArr = Modesend::newInstance()->getprofile();
foreach($newArr as $a) {
 $data[] = $a['profile_id'];
}
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: @Ahmed Glad to help..You can thank me by upvoting and accepting my answer..

Answer (score 0):

This is the simulation of data return from the function **getprofile()**

```
<?php
  $newArr = array (
    0 => array (
      'id' => '1',
      'profile_id' => '57f03c4d66f4a4f6111111111'
    ),
    1 => array (
      'id' => '2',
      'profile_id' => '55534512113e8042222222222'
    ),
  );
?>
```

I don't know what your trying to send to your API but you can store value of a variable to array in this way.

```
<?php
  foreach ($newArr as $key => $value) {
    $values[] = $value['profile_id'];
  }
  var_dump($values);
?>
```